# Laravel 4 - Is there a way I can use just the classes, and not the controllers?

Tags: php, html, laravel, controllers

I'm new at Laravel and frameworks like these in general, but I am wondering if there is a way to exclude the controllers, and just use the very helpful classes (e.g. Session, Pagination, User).

I have already built the majority of my website and I just want a way to **require** the autoloader script and just use the classes when necessary. Is there a way I can achieve this level of picking and choosing from Laravel?
(I am an amateur at the higher level PHP things and Laravel, so feel free to tell me everything I'm saying is nonsense)
Thanks,

Comment: You should learn about [composer package manager](http://getcomposer.org) and know that [Laravel is a set of decoupled components](https://github.com/illuminate) where you can pick (theoretically) one and use this one only. You should look at [symfony](http://http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/index.html) or [aura](http://auraphp.com/packages/), they both offer independent components. IMHO docs for laravel components are not so good, from my own experience I would advice you to go with symfony.

Comment: Perhaps, but without a single entry point into your application things will be a major pain in the a**e. An MVC architecture is actually alot easier to work with than an adhoc collection of php files, you would do yourself a favour by learning it